# Bounds for moving least squares between local curves

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, approximation, least-squares

In moving least squares (see for example [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_least_squares)), you move your window throughout the domain. I have created a graph to illustrate my point further here.

[image]

Let $f(x)$ be the function of interest, and $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are the least squares produced around the point $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively. The shaded area in blue and green indicates the neighbors of $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are included in their corresponding least squares problems.

Let's say I have a point $x_m$ that lies in the intersection between two windows. I want to somehow evaluate how much of a difference the value from each least squares approximation would give me. With referring to the graph, I want to somehow bound:

$$
g_1(x_m) - g_2(x_m)
$$
in some sense. Any suggestions with how I can start? I'm using a 1D example here to easily illustrate my points. Later on, how would I go and generalize it to 3D?

Comment: How did you create this nice chart? What you're after can be achieved by adding a constraint.

Comment: @Royi I used Inkscape. Also, what do you mean by 'adding a constraint'?

Comment: Are you asking what's the bound given using Moving LS or are you asking if one could set a bound and find the solution with the bound as a constraint?

Comment: Your moving least square fit is done with polynomials (degree 2?) or more general?

Comment: @Royi I'm wondering what would the bound be using moving LS.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh For now, I am hoping to start with degree 2 only, but hopefully want to extend to higher degree.